# Fabric.js - object cannot drag/move after centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am using the farbric.js for editing images in an app.
The image should be able to resize, move/drag, and rotate.
The problem is when I rotate the image (by click on the button), it will not in the center of it canvas. So I have to use centerObject() to make it works. 
However, after I done this, the image cannot be drag any more.

this is the function that handling the rotation (it is in a class):

```
 rotationset : function(angle, offsetX, offsetY){
    // this.obj is the origin object  
    this.Obj.left = offsetX;
    this.Obj.top =  offsetY;
    this.Obj.angle = angle;
    this.Obj.center();//center the image
    //this.canvas also initialized on load.
    this.canvas.calcOffset();
    this.canvas.renderAll();

}
```

So, what is the problem? Any other fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation say :

> You might need to call `setCoords` on an object after centering, to update controls area.

So doing `this.Obj.setCoords();` after `this.Obj.center();` should do the trick.

Comment: Always good to see documentation saying that one "might" need to do something sometimes...

Comment: Yes, you are right!! Wonder why I kept missed this sentence.

Comment: When to call `setCoords` is also documented altough it is in the [wiki](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords)